# XP Remove Lexmark printer driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, lexmark-printer

I recently switched my child's XP Home computer from a Lexmark 25 (yard sale, $5) to a Brother printer, because a pair of ink cartridges for the Lexmark are $70 ($60 for refills) versus $2.99/ea for the Brother. Anyway...

I deleted the Lexmark printer drivers from Control Panel/Printers, but when I print to the Brother I get a horrid distorted noise from the speakers that appears to be leftovers from the "now printing" human voice in the Lexmark Drivers.

The Lexmark drivers, of course, do NOT show up in Add/Remove programs. Googling Lexmark removal, I found a lot of old, inapplicable stuff from 2002-3 (apparently the last time anyone used this sort of crap). The spool service names, file names, and registry entries of my later driver do not match these instructions.

Does Lexmark, or anyone else, make a driver removal utility?

**UPDATE:** Since posting this, I've discovered under "Printers and Faxes" that the menu File->Server Properties, Drivers tab, has an Remove option. When I said "deleted" I meant just that, right clicked the driver icon and chose Delete, but I was aware that this would not remove files and probably not unregister DLL's.

Comment: For a future printer purchase, I would highly recommend a cheap laser printer.  You can get Brother and other brands for less than $100.  Generic toner replacements can be $30-40 and run 3000+ pages. It's much more economical.

Comment: Thanks, I like your thinking... I have a Brother B&W laser already, in addition to the Brother MFC that does color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be some registry values that weren't removed when you're driver was uninstalled.

Goto *regedit* & check here if there are any folders from your Lexmark printer left.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers
```

This might be a possible solution.